# Easy way to remember Taylor Series for log(1+x)?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Assuming $|x|<1$, if
one can easily remember that 
$$
\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}
$$
then one can derive the following

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{log}(1-x) & = & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n}\qquad\qquad\mbox{(integrate)}\\
\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}} & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}\qquad\qquad\mbox{(differentiate)}\\
\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^{2}} & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}\qquad\qquad\mbox{(multiply by x)}\\
\dfrac{2}{(1-x)^{3}} & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)nx^{n-2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Is there a similar handy way to remember
\begin{eqnarray*}
log(1+x) & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n}\\
 & = & x-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{x^{3}}{3}-\dfrac{x^{4}}{4}+\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
using either a similar (or a different) approach?

Comment: If you know $\log(1-x)$, just plug $y=-x$ to get $\log(1+y)$

Comment: @Tryss This doesn't give the series the OP gives.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the derivation you have - notably, the first equation, $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n$ is not true - you probably want a log around the sum on the left.

Comment: (take logs) at the right of $\log(1-x)$ should be (take antiderivative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x)^n$$

Can you take it from here? :)

Comment: I think so.

To remember $log(1+x)$ just do
\begin{eqnarray*}
log(1+x) & = & \int\dfrac{dx}{1+x}=\int\dfrac{dx}{1-(-x)}\\
 & = & \int(1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+\cdots)dx\\
 & = & x-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{x^{3}}{3}-\dfrac{x^{4}}{4}+\cdots\\
 & = & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
To remember $log(1-x)$ just do 
\begin{eqnarray*}
log(1-x) & = & -\int\dfrac{dx}{1-x}\\
 & = & -\int(1+x+x^{2}+\cdots)dx\\
 & = & -(x+\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{x^{3}}{3}+\cdots)\\
 & = & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is that correct or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Well in fact I only remember $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\log(2)$ so thats how I remember the power series.

Comment: by a sort of verification? Interesting. I like to remember $e^x$ using the Poisson distribution. (Using that it must sum to 1)